# how to put values in byte array in jni interface

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

here i am passing an empty byte buffer "data" from my java class to this cpp file

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_systems_kestrel_aerovision_datapackets_PacketBuilder_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject,
        jdouble lat, jdouble lng, jdouble altitude, jobject data) {

    jbyte *bbuf_in;

    bbuf_in = (jbyte *) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(data);
    jclass bbclass = env->FindClass( "java/nio/ByteBuffer" );
    jmethodID putMethod = env->GetMethodID(bbclass, "put","(IB)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer");
  //  unsigned char *buffer = stream_buffer(0);

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        env->CallByteMethod( data, putMethod, i, (jbyte)0x7C );
    }
```

it is giving me this error

```
 JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallByteMethodV does not match java.nio.ByteBuffer java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(byte)    in call to CallByteMethodV
```

now i am unable to put values in this data and return to my java class ...please help !!

Answer (score 1):

The `put` method returns the `ByteBuffer` that you wrote to. Since a `ByteBuffer` is a kind of `Object` you should be using `CallObjectMethod` to invoke `put`.